# ASP.NET : serialize and deserialize hashtable with custom type for value

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, hashtable

I want to send a hashtable over a post request; for that I have to convert the hashtable to json.

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON.NET for that.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

User u = new User();
u.name = "username";
u.last = "userlastname";
u.age = 30;

ht.Add("user1", u);
ht.Add("user2", u);
ht.Add("user3", u);
ht.Add("user4", u);

string value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ht);
```

The issue I have is that the value type (`User`) is lost in when deserializing.

Comment: There is no type User in the hash table. It's only user1, user2, user3, user4

Comment: Please, show the content of `string value` and the definition of `User` type

Comment: @Train user1 user2 is only the key the variable u is the type User.

Comment: @JesúsLópez User is an object containing 2 string attributes and one int that I created only for test purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  a TypeNameHandling option of Newtonsoft

```
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };
    string value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ht,jsonSerializerSettings);
    
    ht=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hashtable>(value,jsonSerializerSettings);
```